# inserting values using get method into database

Tags: php, html, sql

i am relatively new in php.The problem that i am facing while i inserting values into 'leave' table of  my database. the error is given below..

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where lid = 4' at line 1

and here is my code

```
<?php

include_once 'config.php';
$accept = "accepted";
mysql_query("insert into `leave` (`action`) values ('$accept') where lid =           ".$_GET['id'] , $dbCon ) or die(mysql_error());  


header('location: admin_leave.php'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **update** for this not **insert**

```
mysql_query("update leave set `action` ='$accept' where lid = ".$_GET['id'] , $dbCon ) or die(mysql_error());
```

and don't use mysql_* they are depreciated link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php . Use either `PDO/mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` can't use with `WHERE`, may be you are looking for `UPDATE`

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `leave` SET `action`='$accept' where lid = ".$_GET['id'] , $dbCon ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Your queries are full open for `SQL Injection`. Start using `Mysqli` OR `PDO` with prepared statement.